# Regex to truncate all words to a maximum word length?

Tags: regex

**EDITED:** How can I use RegEx to match all the words in a sentence and truncate them to a maximum length of 3 letters each? I'm using a search/replace function.

As an example I would like to take this sentence:

```
RegEx to trim all words
```

and return this:

```
Reg to tri all wor
```

but instead I get this:

```
Reg
```

---

I'm using [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/) with the Replace function:

**Search:**

```
^([^\d\W]{3}).*?$
```

**Replace:**

```
$1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please name your tool and show how you apply the regex and the replacement. Is there a `g` option for your `s///` ? Did you use it? Try removing the anchors `^$`, what happens then?

Comment: Is there any special reason for `[^\d\W]{3}` ? From your description I would have expected a simple `\w{3}`.

Comment: @Yunnosch: `[^\d\W]{3}` <==> `[a-zA-Z_]{3}` not `\w{3}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs of [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/regular_expresions)  states that the PCRE is used which supports `\K`

In  the replacement use an empty string.

```
[^\d\W]{3}\K[^\d\W]+
```

- `[^\d\W]{3}` Match 3  word chars except digits
- `\K` Forget what was matched
- `[^\d\W]+` Match 1+ word chars except digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3aQb19/1)

Comment: I think you're going to need to add something to match "the rest of the word", because the OP wants that to be removed.

Comment: @JeffY You are right, I have updated my answer suited for find and replace if supported.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Rubio You are welcome, I have added an update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are matching the whole line with that regex and thus truncating the whole line to its first 3 characters. You don't say what application you're doing the search/replace with. Please edit your question to specify that. But it looks like what you want instead is something like:

```
([^\d\W]{3})[^\d\W]*
```

And you want to use a "replace all" option.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Find: `(\w{0,3})[\w]*`

- `(\w{0,3})` gets first 3 characters ([a-zA-Z0-9_]) of a word (goes into capture group 1)
- `[\w]*` gets the rest of the characters so we can forget about them

Replace with: `\1` (first capture group)

See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aENNn3/1)